# Setting custom page titles for every pages

Tags: php

Currently my site title looks like:

```
<title>My Site Title</title>
```

The above code is added on 'header.php' file, so every pages has the same page title.
I need to set different titles for different pages.

for example,

```
<title>
 if 'contact.php' then title= 'Contact Us'
 else if 'faq.php' then title= 'FAQ'
 else if 'add.php' then title= 'Add'
 else title= 'My Site Title'
</title>
```

somebody please help me!!

Comment: Do you get any errors after writing that pseudo-code into real php? It should work, probably not an optimal solution, but for a small site it should be ok.

Comment: You can create an array with key as page and value as title and access it , but more less it will remain the same , Get the page name from Server request $_SERVER and get the title from array and add to it title

Comment: did you forget to put `<?php` before the first if and add `?>` after `'My Site Title'`?

Answer (score 2):

I guess contact.php `include 'header.php';`. Then something like this would work:

contact.php:

```
<?php
$title = 'Contact Us';
include 'header.php';
// your code
?>
```

header.php:

```
<?php
echo '<title>'.$title.'</title>';
```

Tip: have a look at template engines. I like smarty for example. Maybe someone will comment on this with some other examples ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you to use an array with titles instead of a series of `if`s (respectively a switch)

```
<?php

$file = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$titles = array(
    'contact.php' => 'Contact Us',
    'faq.php' => 'FAQ',
    'add.php' => 'Add',
);

if(array_key_exists($file, $titles){
    echo '<title>'.$titles[$file].'</title>';
}else{
    echo '<title>Ny Site Title</title>';
}

?>
```

Comment: `__FILE__` will allways be /complete/path/to/header.php Moreover you should use isset() which is a language construct and therefore several times faster.

Comment: I used `__FILE__` basically to show where the file name goes, it's up to the OP how they handle that information.

Comment: I don't think someone that asks such a question knows that `__FILE__?` will return the current files name not the requested files name and that he has to use something like `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`.

Comment: @php_nub_qq I'm don't know anything about php, but some basics. My site is a small one with <10 pages. so i want to add diff. titles, I added your code with small changes(in page name) inside <head> of the header.php file, but it's result is an 'error in line 36' :) . Was that the right place??

Comment: @Saly error on line 36 is not really helping, I guess the small changes you made are what is causing this :/

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable in your script called $page and use that variable in the template file.

Business logic for page Home, for example:

```
<?php
.
.
.
$page = 'Home';
render($page);
```

View logic page for Home:

```
.
.
.
<title>
<?php echo $page; ?>
</title>
.
.
.
```

This is just a concept, it is not a fully functional code.

Answer (score 0):

Split your header in to 2 seperate php files, one before the title, and one after the title (this will work with other page specific data, see note at end of answer)

then the top of your pages should look like:

```
<?php include_once("inc/begin-head.inc");?>
<title>My Title</title>
<meta name="description" content="description"></meta>
<?php include_once("inc/end-head.inc");?>
```

There are some other solutions, such as make header a class and define variations to it, and then call a function to output the head completly

Please note, there are a LOT of other paged specific tags. Title, Meta Description, Canonical url link, meta keywords, open graph data .....

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this and use basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) and now lookup for the $title[key]

```
           $title = array();
           $title['home.php'] = 'My home page';
           $title['Hello.php'] = 'My title';
```

Answer (score 0):

To add title dynamically , first set the following code in header.php file :

```
<title> 
    <?php 
        if(isset($title) && !empty($title)) { 
            echo $title; 
        } else { 
            echo "Default title tag"; 
        }
    ?>
</title>
```

and set title in each page before including header as :

```
$title = "Your Title";
include 'header.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

How I did this for anyone curious in the future...

I have a "pagetitles.php" page that contains this code:

```
 $page_files=array(
  "admin"=>"Admin Panel",
  "profile"=>"Your Profile",
  "billing"=>"Billing / Subscriptions",
  "pricing"=>"Our Pricing",
  "settings"=>"Your Settings",
  "bugs"=>"Bug/Feature Tracker",
  "search"=>"Search Results",
  "clients"=>"My Clients");

if(isset($_GET['rq'])){
if(in_array($_GET['rq'],array_keys($page_files))) {
$pagetitle = $page_files[$_GET['rq']];
}
}
```

Then I include that file at the very top of my index.php page, and echo $pagetitle where I want the title to be. BUT this also requires another file to handle serving the specific pages, using a ?rq request

In my "page_dir.php" file, I have the following that handles ?rq= pages (ex: [www.example.com?rq=home](http://www.example.com?rq=home) will load the home page, with the above page title that's inside of "home" array)

Here's the page_dir.php file:

```
$page_files=array(
    "noaccess"=>"pages/noaccess.php",
    "home"=>"pages/dashboard/home.php",
    "lists"=>"pages/dashboard/lists.php"
  );

if(isset($_GET['rq'])){
if(in_array($_GET['rq'],array_keys($page_files))) {
      include $page_files[$_GET['rq']];
}else{
      include $page_files['home'];
}}else{
    include $page_files['home'];
}
```

This page_dir.php file, I put on the index page where I want main content to show up at... I then have each individual page with just the content (like home.php file is just home.php content without the navbar and footer)

On my index.php file, where I want the page title, I have this code:

```
    if(isset($code_nav_title)){
      echo $code_nav_title;
    }elseif(isset($pagetitle)){
      echo $pagetitle;
    }else{
      echo "Default Page Title Here";
    }
```

the $code_nav_title lets me set the page title from form submissions if I want it to say "success" or "failed" :) the "default page title here" lets you set something to automatically show up if everything fails to show (like if you forgot to set the page title)

Hopefully this makes sense! It's saved me sooo many headaches and makes it easy for expansion/changes!